# What is this cylindrical black component with a wire looped through it?

Tags: identification, components

Could anyone tell me what this component is? Thank you

[image: unknown component]

Comment: Ferrite bead. For EMI.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this: -

[image]

[6 hole ferrite bead suppressor](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/WE-UKW/) made by Wurth: -

**Characteristics**

- Impedance will increase with more turns, available in 1 to 3 turns
- 4 different materials available for perfect interference suppression
- Also available ready-bent or in individual length
- Maximum current capability is 3 A / 5 A (short-time)
- Operating temperature: –25 ºC to +125 ºC

[Application note](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/media/o109029v410%20AppNotes_ANP015_MainFilterTheLastBarrierInASMPS_EN.pdf)

Different manufacturers have slightly different hole layouts: -

[image]

[VK200 Inductors](https://www.rf-microwave.com/en/vk200-inductors/220/).

This one is made by Ferroxcube: -

[image]

[Purchase link](https://uk.farnell.com/ferroxcube/mhc6-6-10-4b1/ferrite-core-cylindrical/dp/219850?gclid=Cj0KCQjwp4j6BRCRARIsAGq4yMFOlM_zNtoWcIwdDhoJwzluvgNGCmhwE6tYV3KR0S1EbAgOlOhsJlwaAhMYEALw_wcB&gross_price=true&mckv=s4M7IesvV_dc%7Cpcrid%7C431236176234%7Cplid%7C%7Ckword%7C%7Cmatch%7C%7Cslid%7C%7Cproduct%7C219850%7Cpgrid%7C95483804810%7Cptaid%7Cpla-904092883148%7C&CMP=KNC-GUK-SHOPPING-Passive-components-NEWSTRUCTURE-Test113-MarinBidding)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike wideband low-pass filters, [ferrite beads](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/WE-UKW/) can block a selected range of frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has four wires coming out of the bottom. If that's the case, it's probably a transformer.